# Change the value of a text box from code VB.NET in Report Viewer Reports

Tags: vb.net, rdl

I have a report drawn through SSRB 3.0.
The report is of the .rdl type so through VB.NET code and Report Viewer is hooked and displayed.
The data set is managed dynamically so that records can be filtered according to the user's needs.

The report is very simple has:

1. a page header with a text box (TestataREp) with the value: 'ACTIVITY LIST';
2. in the body a table that displays the records according to the dataset;
3. a footer with the numbering of the pages.

Since the data to be displayed are filtered according to the user's choices, I would like to be able to dynamically change the value of the textbox (the Header) in the page header or with another text box as a dynamically editable subtitle from code vb.net, but I do not know how to do it.

In practice I would like, for example, that the header could be changed, via code vb.net, from 'ACTIVITY LIST' to 'ACTIVITY LIST of the xxxx group'
or in 'LiSTA PERSONAL ACTIVITIES' etc. etc.
I don't know if I could explain myself.
Thank you for any useful advice.

Comment: Could you bind the control(s) in your report header to properties of the report.  Then just update that property and the bindings should handle the rest for you

Comment: How do I aggrate a control (textBox) that is in the report header from code vb.net?
Could you please give me an indication of code to understand how to do it? Thank you

Comment: I think this may kinda help you @Antony . https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17631288/pass-textbox-data-to-rdlc-report